# How to use keywords parameters in powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, keyword

I have a simple script:

```
function getops {
[CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$server,
    [string]$name,
    [string]$user,
    [string]$password,
    [string]$url,
    [string]$acl

  )
    echo $server
    echo $name
    echo $user
    echo $password
    echo $url
    echo $acl
}

getops
```

But when i am trying to call this script with arguments.

```
.\Untitled2.ps1 -server my\sqlexpress -name my -user my_user -password my_password -url 192.168.0.1 -acl 192.168.0.1:5000
```

I see empty result.

When i am adding to function inside the script needed argument

```
function getops {
[CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$server,
    [string]$name,
    [string]$user,
    [string]$password,
    [string]$url,
    [string]$acl

  )
    echo $server
    echo $name
    echo $user
    echo $password
    echo $url
    echo $acl
}

getops -server my\sqlexpress -name my -user my_user -password my_password -url 192.168.0.1 -acl 192.168.0.1:5000
```

I see result, that i need:

```
my\sqlexpress
my
my_user
my_password
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1:5000
```

The question, how to receive the same result in powershell, via calling script with keyword parameters, like this:

`.\Untitled2.ps1 -server my\sqlexpress -name my -user my_user -password my_password -url 192.168.0.1 -acl 192.168.0.1:5000`

The main task to receive these parameters into variables and to put these variables to the different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use parameters in the script by the same way as in the function
write the script with the param block

```
param
(
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$server,
  [string]$name,
  [string]$user,
  [string]$password,
  [string]$url,
  [string]$acl

)
echo $server
echo $name
echo $user
echo $password
echo $url
echo $acl
```

then run script

```
.\Untitled2.ps1 -server my\sqlexpress -name my -user my_user -password my_password -url 192.168.0.1 -acl 192.168.0.1:5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Define another param block outside the function, so that the parameters can be passed to your script. In your case you just call the function without parameters.

```
# Untitled2.ps1

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$server,
    [string]$name,
    [string]$user,
    [string]$password,
    [string]$url,
    [string]$acl
)

function getops {
  param
  (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$server,
    [string]$name,
    [string]$user,
    [string]$password,
    [string]$url,
    [string]$acl
  )
  echo $server
  echo $name
  echo $user
  echo $password
  echo $url
  echo $acl
}

getops -server $server -name $name -user $user -password $password -url $url -acl $acl
```

Then you can call your script via

```
.\Untitled2.ps1 -server my\sqlexpress -name my -user my_user -password my_password -url 192.168.0.1 -acl 192.168.0.1:5000
```